# A non well formed numeric value encountered during generate id

Tags: php

I am trying to generate unique number for my requirements like below

```
$click_id = intval(microtime() + floor(rand()));
```

Its working fine and giving me proper result like

1307460753

But I am getting warning called

A non well formed numeric value encountered in line 3.

I have tried remove `intval` but its still same. Let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: `microtime` returns a string.

Comment: @0stone0 then I should $click_id = intval(intval(microtime()) + floor(rand())); correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`microtime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) return a string, pass `true` as the first parameter to enable `as_float`, so you can perform the math you'd like:

```php
<?php

$click_id = intval(microtime(true) + floor(rand()));

echo $click_id;
```